# MWFeedParser Enclosures

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, rss

I am using the MWFeedParser (found here: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser).  I followed his example app, but it doesn't include enclosures.  I am looking for someone to help me add enclosures to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access enclosures with `MWFeedParser`. I've done it. They're stored in `item.enclosures` where `item` is the `MWFeedItem`.

Comment: Look at the readme for `MWFeedParser` it explains everything very clearly.